# Can I allow the user to specify the order of static columns in SSRS tablix?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report in SSRS 2008 (not R2) with a table of up to around 30 columns that are displayed dynamically based on an input parameter.  I've been asked to allow the user to choose the order in which the columns are displayed.  We have done something similar for groups of columns that are automatically generated in a Matrix, but in this case the columns are static.

At this point, I have an input parameter that allows the user to specify their desired sort order, but I don't know how to apply the order to the columns.  Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: Are all the columns the same width, or can they be set to the same width?

Comment: Also, can you describe your column sort input parameter? What sort of data does it take?

Comment: I can probably come up with a way to do this dynamic columns but what does the input parameter look like?

Comment: The input parameter is a string that is formatted as in the following example:  "columnAname|1||columnBname|2||columnCname|3||"  where the integers following each column name are altered by the user to indicate their desired order.  The columns are of varying datatypes and will have varying widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot dynamically order static columns in SSRS.

Only dynamically generated columns (i.e. through grouping) can be ordered in this way.  If the requirement is to have variable width columns ordered dynamically, this is beyond the capabilities of SSRS.

However, you could have several different "column width types" (e.g. short, medium, long), where you create a column for each "column width type", group the columns together under the dynamic column grouping and set each column's visibility based on a "column width type" field specified in the dataset.